# How do I update a ScrollView in SwiftUI upon updating array of objects it displays?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, horizontalscrollview

I am finishing up my first SwiftUI app and I ran into this problem that I can't seem to solve. I have a horizontal ScrollView that displays an array of user-created *Categories*, and I have a button in the navigation bar that opens a presented "Toast" view; allowing the user to add a *Category*. Upon tapping the button within the presenting "Toast" view, the view closes itself, adds the new *Category* to the collection of category documents I have in my Firebase database, and then updates the global *categories* array within my app based on the online data. All of this is done successfully (I can see in my online database the document is created, and upon completion of updating the global *categories* array I printed its contents and it also checked out). However, the ScrollView remains unchanged, even though it is displaying the array which has been updated. **The only time the ScrollView updates is when I reboot the app, or when I sign-out and sign back in.** Basically what I want to do is this:

**How do I properly update the ScrollView instantaneously, knowing my data (the global *categories* array) has been updated? Do I need to make the *categories* array an Observable Object? And if so, how would I implement that?**

An additional note, the *categories* array is located in my local data file, along with the functions that update it accordingly, such as the *getUserCategories* function in the Toast View below.

Here is my Categories view:

```
struct CategoriesView: View {
    @State var showToast: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Background{
                VStack{
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                        HStack(spacing: 20){
                            ForEach(categories){ category1 in
                                GeometryReader{ geometry in
                                    CategoryCardView(
                                        category: category1
                                    )
                                        .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(geometry.frame(in: .global).minX) - 40) / -20, axis: (x: 0, y: 10.0, z: 0))
                                }.frame(width: 300, height: 550)
                            }
                        }.padding(.leading, 40).padding(.trailing, 40)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 460)
                .navigationBarTitle("Categories").navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showToast.toggle()
                    }
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "folder.fill.badge.plus").resizable()
                        .frame(width:50, height:35)
                })
            }.onTapGesture(perform: endEditing)
        }.toast(isShowing: self.$showToast)
    }
    private func endEditing() {
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
        showToast = false
    }
}
```

And here is my "Toast" presented view (It isn't that relevant to the problem, but I thought I would include it anyway as the two views go hand in hand):

```
struct Toast<Presenting>: View where Presenting: View {

    /// The binding that decides the appropriate drawing in the body.
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool

    /// The view that will be "presenting" this toast
    let presenting: () -> Presenting
    /// The text to show
    @State private var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in

            ZStack(alignment: .center) {

                self.presenting()
                    .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 3 : 0)

                VStack {
                    TextField("Category Name", text: self.$text)
                        .padding(.leading)
                        .padding(.trailing)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 40)
                        .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                        .cornerRadius(3)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 40)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                    Button(action:{
                        withAnimation{
                            let cUser = Firebase.Auth.auth().currentUser
                            let db = Firestore.firestore()

                            //NEW CATEGORY IS ADDED TO DATABASE

                            let newCategory =  db.collection("users").document(cUser!.uid).collection("categories").document()
                            newCategory.setData(["id":newCategory.documentID, "name": self.text])

                            //GLOBAL ARRAY UDPATES HERE

                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                                getUserCategories()
                            }

                            UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
                            self.isShowing = false
                        }
                    }){
                        Text("Create Category")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 30) .background(Color.black)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 1.5,
                       height: geometry.size.height / 5)
                    .background(Color.primary.colorInvert())
                .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .transition(.slide)
                .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide me with. Have a good day everyone and happy coding!

Comment: What is `categories` in `ForEach` and where and how it is modified?

Comment: It is a global array of "Category" objects (that is displayed in the ScrollView via the ForEach) that is located in my Data file for my app and is modified there as well.

Comment: So if it is simple array, there is no mechanism that notifies view to reload it from there, so the simplest is to make it @Published and wrap in some `ObservableObject` that can be used as `ObservedObject` view model inside view, so view be notified of `categories` changes.